# Sentence Structure Question (Is it acceptable?)

Tags: grammar, phrases, punctuation

I just came across this sentence while studying for the SAT and wonder if it makes sense.

**The women soon disperse, SOME entering the shallow waters at the beach, OTHERS venturing out onto the rocks to access deeper waters.**

My first question is, it sounds a little awkward to add some additional fragments beginning with SOME and OTHERS here. Are they participial phrases? Can they be added like this beginning with SOME and OTHERS?

My second question is, can they be added with just a comma? SOME ... , OTHERS ... I feel there should be some conjunctions to make it more natural.

This makes me so confused. I'd really appreciate it if you could enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: The comma between Some and Others is natural. I'd look for anything that's not a comma before the first Some. "The women soon disperse--SOME."

Comment: Are you aware of what a [nominative absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute) (sometimes known by other names) is? If not, you may want to look through some of [this site's questions on that topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-constructions) and, if those don't answer your question, update your question [describing the research that you did and why it didn't help](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043).

Comment: The sentence is fine. The "some" and "others" expressions are non-finite clauses serving as supplements; more specifically they are absolute constructions.

Comment: Right. _Some_ and _others_ stand for _some women_ and _other women_ (note the plural on the noun and its coreferential determiner _others_), and the sentence just has three clauses -- one main clause specifying a group division, and two cognate participial clauses detailing the divisions separately.

Comment: @BillJ +1 for your comment, but just for completeness' sake I'll note that some references classify the nominative absolute as a *phrase* rather than a clause.  I have seen both designations, but believe 'phrase' *may?* be more common.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or four, perhaps, if we analyse *to access deeper waters* as a clause.

Answer (score 3):

That's a perfectly good sentence, and the *some doing this, others doing that* structure is often used.

> Animals adapt to the change of seasons differently, some hibernating during the
> winter when food is scarce, others changing color in order to be less
> conspicuous as prey.
>
> People look for different things in a car, some preferring a powerful
> engine that can deliver speed, others focusing on fuel-efficiency
> for their daily commute.

It is a form of *parataxis* [[see the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis)].

You will often find the coordination of ideas expressed without parataxis:

> People look for different things in a car, **with** some preferring a powerful engine that can deliver speed **and** others focusing on fuel-efficiency for their daily commute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know why the "Community" bot posted that comment,              since anyone could look up the crucial word there if they wanted. Your "coordination of ideas expressed without parataxis" example is clear as day to me, but I added a link to Wikipedia anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way it's written is choppy and a confusing, because the word "soon" implies the future, but the rest of it implies that the action is already happening and happened. It should have been written one of these ways to convey the information more clearly:

**Past**

- *"The women DISPERSED. Some ENTERED the shallow waters at the beach,
  WHILE others VENTURED out onto the rocks to access deeper waters."*

**Present**

- *"The women disperse, entering the shallow waters at the beach, while

  others venture TOWARDS the rocks to access deeper waters."*

**Future**

- *"The women WILL SOON disperse WITH some entering the shallow waters

  at the beach, WHILE others WILL venture out onto the rocks to access
  deeper waters."*